# Send Email Core Action Recipient Id

Tags: send-email, flowsupport

Can anyone help me understand why recipient id of send email core action does not accept user id as input parameter and only accepts lead,contact or person account ids only?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is mentioned in the official documentation:

> **Recipient ID**
>
> *Optional*. The ID of a lead, contact, or person account record. Required if Email Template ID is specified. If Log Email on Send is
> included, this parameter is the ID of the person to send and log the
> email to. If Email Template ID is included, this parameter is the ID
> of the person to send an email to and populate recipient merge fields
> with. If the ID entered in this parameter is a lead record, you can’t
> use Related Record ID. You can enter a value for Recipient ID,
> Recipient Address List, and Recipient Address Collection as long as
> the combined number of recipients is five or fewer.**

Please refer to below link for more information:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_actions_sendemail.htm&type=5

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I have updated the answer.Thanks for highlighting it.

Answer (score 0):

I also share the same question. When you use an Email Template from an Email Alert you don't need to specify anything that odd: there may very well **not** be any lead, contact or person account related to the email that needs to be sent!

Why do you have to specify this from the Send Email core action???